# Update data to tab Fragment Android when swipe

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, tabs, fragment

I have a problem with my code, and i try fix it by search google but not work. 
I try writing a karaoke List App to view list songs and favorite songs.This app have 2 Fragment Tab, List and Favorite, I want that when user click add Favorite in List Tab or Favorite tab, favorite tab will be updated immediately. But it not work. I must restart my app to view result. I try to refresh Favorite tab by getItem but it not work.

Here is my code, please help me, thanks very much.
Main Activity:

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    adapter.addFrag(new DanhSach(), "  ZANHSÁCH");
    adapter.addFrag(new YeuThich(), "  YÊUTHÍCH");
    adapter.addFrag(new LienHe(), "  LIÊNHỆ");
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);
     viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {

            return super.getItemPosition(object);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
       return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return null;
        //return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

Favorite Class:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.yeuthich, container, false);
    ListView lvdanhsach = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvyeuthich);
    MainActivity main1 = (MainActivity) getActivity();

    YtAdapter = new BaiHatAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.items,main1.dsYeuthich);
    YtAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    lvdanhsach.setAdapter(YtAdapter);


    return view;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `ViewPager` at the same moment not on only visible `Fragment` is loaded, but also the next one, so `onCreateView` of second Fragment will be called at the very beginning of the `Activity`. Therefore you should call `notifyDatasetChanged` not in the `onCreateView`, but later when you add the song.

Comment: I did that but it not work, my code is when user click like each song, this song will be update to database and display favorite tab. But it only update to database and not show up in favorite tab untill restart app.

Comment: Can you post some code of that? Also, you use some custom adapter. Is it a `CursorAdapter`? If yes, are you swapind cursor after operation on database?

Comment: it's available for editting, please help me and tks so much.

Answer (score 0):

My comment would be too long, so I post it in different answer.

There are few errors in your code.

1. You have to know the difference between `notifyDataSetChanged` and `notifyAll`. The first is about refreshing the adapter, and the second one is about waking up threads (I quess, that it isn't wat you wanted)
2. Your adapters are `ArrayAdapter`s so they base on the inner `ArrayList`. Both your adapters keep `ArrayList` from `MainActivity`. In method `addDsYeuThich` you add element to the list, but you have to nofity adapter in the second fragment. To do that, in `MainActicity` you have to keep the reference to this fragment and notify its adapter at the end of this method. What is more, at the beginning of `addDsYeuThich` you reinitialize the `ArrayList`. You cannot do that, as the secondFragment still keeps the old list. You should initialize this list only once (i.e. in onCreate) and in `addDsYeuThich` only call `clear`.

If you have more problems, let me know.

Comment: i try do it but it not work, hope you can edit my code in GitHub here:

Comment: github.com/anhpha90/KaraokeList
I wanna vote your comment but I can't because of minimum 15 reputation.  Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: i want to find a method get event when user swipe change tab like  but it not work,

Comment: I've seen you repo. Sorry, but I won't write code for you, As far as I can see, you haven't changed anything after my last comment. Try to push your changes to github, so I can see what you've done. The most changes are about `addDsYeuThich` method.

Comment: Tks for your help, i can do it by recall method addYehthich when user click like but maybe it not Optimal. Tks so much again

Comment: Isn't that what you have been doing from the beginning? Anyway, did you manage to solve your problem?